# Java 17 solution for Spark - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-17

There are some solutions here

[Windows Spark Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690402/windows-spark-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-o)

The mentioned error probably corresponds to the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x12a94400) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module
```

Switching back to Java 11 or below is not a solution for me. How can this be solved with Java 17?

Comment: You do not need any level of reputation to answer. Spark officially only supports Java 11

Comment: As of Spark 3.3.0, Java 17 is supported -- however, it still references `sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer` so the `--add-exports` mentioned in the answer below is still required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark 3.3.0 breaks on Java 17 with "cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73465937/spark-3-3-0-breaks-on-java-17-with-cannot-access-class-sun-nio-ch-directbuffer)

Answer (score 11):

You can solve this problem (and about each and every Java 17 problem) by adding a `--add-exports` statement to the corresponding Java call. In this case `--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED`.

Comment: I tried adding the export statement to maven-surefire-plugin in pom.xml but the same error message persist, do you know why? @OneCricketeer

Comment: This text was written by @ArndEden in the original post and moved here as an answer

Comment: Solved this by adding the above `--add-exports` statement to `vmArgs` in launch.json on VSCode. Adding to maven-surefire-plugin in pom.xml did nothing for me.

Comment: Also consider setting `-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true` when using Apache Arrow library. 
---
Per https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html - For Java 11, -Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true is required additionally for Apache Arrow library. This prevents java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: sun.misc.Unsafe or java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.(long, int) not available when Apache Arrow uses Netty internally.