# Running unit tests with Spark 3.3.0 on Java 17 fails with IllegalAccessError: class StorageUtils cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-17

According to the [release notes](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-3-3-0.html), and specifically the ticket *Build and Run Spark on Java 17 ([SPARK-33772](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33772))*, Spark now supports running on Java 17.

However, using Java 17 (Temurin-17.0.3+7) with Maven (3.8.6) and maven-surefire-plugin (3.0.0-M7), when running a unit test that uses Spark (3.3.0) it fails with:

> `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x1e7ba8d9) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x1e7ba8d9`

The stack is:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x1e7ba8d9) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x1e7ba8d9
  at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:353)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:290)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:339)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:194)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:279)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:464)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947)
  [...]
```

The question [*Java 17 solution for Spark - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72230174) was asked only 2 months ago, but this pre-dated the Spark 3.3.0 release, and thus predated official support for Java 17.

Why can't I run my Spark 3.3.0 test with Java 17, and how can we fix it?

Comment: FWIW, it actually broke for me in 3.2.3 and was fixed in 3.3.1.

Comment: That was it works from spark-submit, but not if I try to run it via sbt test in unit (actually acceptance/integration) tests, even in local mode (cluster or client mode).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though Spark now supports Java 17, it still references the JDK internal class `sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer`:

```
  // In Java 8, the type of DirectBuffer.cleaner() was sun.misc.Cleaner, and it was possible
  // to access the method sun.misc.Cleaner.clean() to invoke it. The type changed to
  // jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner in later JDKs, and the .clean() method is not accessible even with
  // reflection. However sun.misc.Unsafe added a invokeCleaner() method in JDK 9+ and this is
  // still accessible with reflection.
  private val bufferCleaner: DirectBuffer => Unit = [...]
```

Under the Java module system, access to this class is restricted.  The [Java 9 migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm) says:

> If you must use an internal API that has been made inaccessible by default, then you can break encapsulation using the --add-exports command-line option.

We need to open access to our module.  To do this for Surefire, we add this configuration to the plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Based on a [discussion with one of the Spark developers](https://lists.apache.org/thread/814cpb1rpp73zkhtv9t4mkzzrznl82yn), Spark adds the following in order to execute all of its internal unit tests.

> These options are used to pass all Spark UTs, but maybe you don't need all.

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED
```

It was also commented:

> However, these Options needn't explicit add when using spark-shell, spark-sql and spark-submit

Comment: Is there a Spark ticket open to fix this?

Comment: Surely those options are overkill. Does someone want to investigate further. I imagine most of options would work with `--add-exports` instead of `--add-opens` (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html)), because surely Spark isn't using reflection on all those packages. For a simple use case of reading CSV files and saving to JSON locally, just `--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED` is working for me. Still we shouldn't have this problem in the first place. Does Spark intend to fix this?

Comment: @GarretWilson The link to the `user@spark.apache.org` [mailing list discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread/814cpb1rpp73zkhtv9t4mkzzrznl82yn) is in the answer if you want to take up the discussion with Yang Jie further.

Comment: This would be for a spark-submit, but can we fix this in scala code/testing (kicked off with sbt)?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the discussions above I am using:

```
%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit.cmd --driver-java-options "--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED" spark_ml_heart.py
```

with a single `--add-exports` to run a Python script on Spark 3.2.1 on Java 17.

You may need the full version with all `--add-exports`:

```
%SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit.cmd --driver-java-options "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED" spark_ml_heart.py
```

Comment: How can I add the options inside supark-submit.cmd so that I can use pyspark inside my IDE (PyCharm)?

Comment: The single adjustment (first option) worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, it worked for me for a spark-submit with spark 3.2, but I'm still not seeing anywhere in this answer how to run scala tests (like with sbt) on a spark project. Even with spark 3.3, I still get the OP's error, so something is configured differently with `sbt test` than a `spark-submit --master=local[*]`.

Answer (score 2):

After fixing some of these errors, I got an error with the KryoSerializer:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create serializer "com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer" for class: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
```

I got around this issue by adding some of the VM arguments aforementioned by @Greg Kopff to my pom.xml (I am using maven):

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${scalatest-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>
                --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
                --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
                --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
            </argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```