# Apache Spark 3.3.0 breaks on Java 17 with "cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer"

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-17

A similar question was asked at [Running unit tests with Spark 3.3.0 on Java 17 fails with IllegalAccessError: class StorageUtils cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72724816), but that question (and solution) was only about unit tests. For me Spark is breaking actually running the program.

According to the [Spark overview](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/), Spark works with Java 17. I'm using Temurin-17.0.4+8 (build 17.0.4+8) on Windows 10, including Spark 3.3.0 in Maven like this:

```xml
<scala.version>2.13</scala.version>
<spark.version>3.3.0</spark.version>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
  <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
  <version>${spark.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I try to run a simple program:

```java
final SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Foo Bar").master("local").getOrCreate();
final Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "false").load("/path/to/file.csv");
df.show(5);
```

That breaks all over the place:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x59d016c9) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x59d016c9
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:353)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947)
```

Spark is obviously doing things one is not supposed to do in Java 17.

Disappointing. How do I get around this?

Comment: Not much of a choice : you need to add the `--add-opens` options cited in the linked post to your program launch command. I find it strange that Spark has not already addressed such problem though.

Comment: IMO it would be better for you to downgrade to JDK 8 or JDK 11 if you can. JDK 17 support was just recently added so this might not be your last issue with that...

Comment: FWIW, it actually broke for me in 3.2.3 and appeared fixed in 3.3.1.

Comment: it happens on 3.2.2 too; i have to use 3.2.2 due to spark-excel dependency

Answer (score 39):

## Solution

> A similar question was asked at [Running unit tests with Spark 3.3.0 on Java 17 fails with IllegalAccessError: class StorageUtils cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72724816), but that question (and solution) was only about unit tests. For me Spark is breaking actually running the program.

Please, consider adding the appropriate Java Virtual Machine command-line options.
The exact way to add them depends on how you run the program: by using a command line, an IDE, etc.

### Examples

The command-line options have been taken from the `JavaModuleOptions` class: [spark/JavaModuleOptions.java at v3.3.0 · apache/spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.0/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/JavaModuleOptions.java).

#### Command line

For example, to run the program (the `.jar` file) by using the command line:

```bash
java \
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED \
    --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED \
    -jar <JAR_FILE_PATH>
```

#### IDE: IntelliJ IDEA

References:

- [Run/debug configurations | IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2022.2/run-debug-configuration.html): Search for the «Add VM options» string.
- [java - How to set JVM arguments in IntelliJ IDEA? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938383/how-to-set-jvm-arguments-in-intellij-idea).

## References

- [Running unit tests with Spark 3.3.0 on Java 17 fails with IllegalAccessError: class StorageUtils cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72724816/running-unit-tests-with-spark-3-3-0-on-java-17-fails-with-illegalaccesserror-cl).

  - [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72724817).

    - [Re: [Java 17] --add-exports required?-Apache Mail Archives](https://lists.apache.org/thread/814cpb1rpp73zkhtv9t4mkzzrznl82yn).
- [[SPARK-33772] Build and Run Spark on Java 17 - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33772).
- [spark/JavaModuleOptions.java at v3.3.0 · apache/spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.0/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/JavaModuleOptions.java).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's a pity no one investigates this further Surely those options (copied from an email thread) are overkill. I imagine most of options would work with `--add-exports` instead of `--add-opens` (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html)), because surely Spark isn't using reflection on all those packages. For a simple use case of reading CSV files and saving to JSON locally, just --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED is working for me.

Comment: Does anyone intend to fix this? Is there a Spark ticket filed?

Comment: Dear @GarretWilson, I have updated the answer to specify that the command-line options have been taken from the `JavaModuleOptions` class: [spark/JavaModuleOptions.java at v3.3.0 · apache/spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.0/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/JavaModuleOptions.java).

Comment: @GarretWilson, I don't have such information. I did a quick search and found a related ticket: [\[SPARK-35557\] Adapt uses of JDK 17 Internal APIs - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-35557). Please, note the [solution comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-35557?focusedCommentId=17441883&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17441883): `--add-opens` is mentioned as the solution. Maybe, it is worth reopening the ticket or opening a new one.

Comment: I'm going to assign the bounty to this answer as you put a lot of work into it and it gives some good references. Still it doesn't provide a sufficient solution or more in-depth tests for me consider it the accepted answer. Sure, I know I can cram a lot of coarse, brute-force exceptions and figure one of them will cover the Spark limitations. I'm looking for something more finely tuned, and a path forward for getting this fixed in Spark.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it worked from intelliJ, who launches the app using `java -jar`. If I am working in a cluster, do you know if I should set this options as driver and executor extra java options? I tried it on the code (on the Spark Application builder) but here it does not seem to be working

Comment: You are a life saver this is necessary for sparkNLP if you are trying to use it with java and I had to add it to vm arguments with run for eclipse.

Answer (score 37):

Following step helped me to unblock the issue.

If you are running the application from **IDE (intelliJ IDEA)** follow the below instructions.

Add the JVM option  "--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"

[image]

source: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/install.html#java-compatibility

Answer (score 16):

These three methods work for me on a project using

- Spark 3.3.2
- Scala 2.13.10
- Java 17.0.6 (my project is small, it even works on Java 19.0.1. However, if your project is big, it is better to wait Spark officially supports it)

### Method 1

```bash
export JAVA_OPTS='--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED'
sbt run
```

### Method 2

Create a **.jvmopts** file in your project folder, with content:

```
--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Then you can run

```bash
sbt run
```

### Method 3

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, this is based on @Anil Reddaboina's answer, and thanks!

This adds more info as I don't have that "VM Options" field by default.

Follow this:

[image]

Then you should be able to add `--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED` to "VM Options" field.

or add fully necessary VM Options arguments:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For those using Gradle to run unit tests for Spark, apply this in `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
 
    val sparkJava17CompatibleJvmArgs = listOf(
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED",
    )
    jvmArgs = sparkJava17CompatibleJvmArgs
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use JDK 8. You maybe should really.

But if you can't you might try adding to your `build.sbt` file these java options. For me they were needed for tests so I put them into:

```scala
val projectSettings = Seq(
...
  Test / javaOptions ++= Seq(
    "base/java.lang", "base/java.lang.invoke", "base/java.lang.reflect", "base/java.io", "base/java.net", "base/java.nio",
    "base/java.util", "base/java.util.concurrent", "base/java.util.concurrent.atomic",
    "base/sun.nio.ch", "base/sun.nio.cs", "base/sun.security.action",
    "base/sun.util.calendar", "security.jgss/sun.security.krb5",
  ).map("--add-opens=java." + _ + "=ALL-UNNAMED"),
...
```

Comment: I'm really curious about this, because it's the only answer targeted toward tests, but it didn't work for me. Would you be willing to link a minimum working example or the rest of your sparkConf/sparkSession.builder command or something?

Comment: Wow - after a ton of work, I figured out how to fix this by following your first suggestion to just use java 8. I'll try to post more tips for other soon. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: @combinatorist yes I think the java options for the tests was specific to our setup at the time. Generally sticking to jdk8 is more of a broad stroke workaround. I'm sorry the specific options didn't work for your case.

Comment: The above suggestion of adding Test / javaOptions ++ ... worked for me in vscode when all other suggestions didn't. Thank you.

Comment: JDK 17, Spark 3.3.2. Out of all the different solutions posited, this is the one that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Add this as explicit dependency in Pom.xml file. Don't change version other than 3.0.16

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

and then add the command line arguments. If you use VS code, add

```
"vmArgs": "--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

in configurations section in `launch.json` file under `.vscode` folder in  your project.

Comment: `vmArgs` param should go in `launch.json` as per the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch)

Answer (score 2):

simply upgrade to spark 3.3.2 solved my problem

I use Java 17 and pyspark in the command line.

Comment: Just add more info. In my case, for PySpark, I never had this issue no matter which Spark version. For Scala projects, I am on Spark 3.3.2, unfortunately, this does not help, and I still need `--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED`.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this using JDK 21 and Spark 3.5.0

```
  <properties>
        <spark.version>3.5.0</spark.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

Add below line as VM Option in IntelliJ Idea

**--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED**

And It Works!

Answer (score 1):

I saw this while trying to set up and run a job against a spark standalone cluster in docker.

I tried all possible combinations of passing the `--add-opens` directives via `spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions`, `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`, `spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions`, `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`.

None worked. My guess is that there isn't a mechanism to decorate the spark-submit Java entrypoint with these options.

In the end I did this in the base docker image, which solved the problem:

`ENV JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS='--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED ...'`

JVM (-D...) properties can be passed to the job via: `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`. No idea why JVM options are not picked up at this phase.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has the same problem try adding the list of opens from
chehsunliu's answer (tweaked for groovy):

```
def sparkJava17CompatibleJvmArgs = [
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED"
]

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'com.cool.App'
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = sparkJava17CompatibleJvmArgs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://blog.jdriven.com/2023/03/mastering-maven-setting-default-jvm-options-using-jvm-config/

Simple fix that worked for me:

1. Add a .mvn folder to the root directory of your project
2. Create a jvm.config file and add `--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED`

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bla8f.png)