# Unrecognized option: --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED from Docker container

Tags: docker, apache-spark, java-17, javaoptions

I would appreciate your assistance in resolving the issue I have encountered

While addressing [Apache Spark 3.3.0 breaks on Java 17 with "cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73465937/apache-spark-3-3-0-breaks-on-java-17-with-cannot-access-class-sun-nio-ch-direct) problem
I have attempted to implement the suggested solution, which functions successfully when running my code from IntelliJ.

However, I need to execute my final code within a Docker image. I have approached this by specifying the necessary VM options in a straightforward manner. Here is an example of how I have specified the required options:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED" ...
```

I have tried various options and I am confident that they are all correct.
Unfortunately, regardless of the options I choose, I consistently encounter the following result:

```
Unrecognized option: --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I experimented with various images, without a big success.

All image are running with the same JAVA version I tried on my MAC+IntelliJ

```
openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.7.7.1 (build 17.0.7+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.7.7.1 (build 17.0.7+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.