# Spark RDD ADI's using scala programing intelliJ

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I want to create a Spark API program using Scala, and when adding the Spark context, this exception appears."

I have:

- spark version 3.5.0
- scala version 2.12.18
- jdk-19

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x47542153) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x47542153
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:483)
    at ReadCSVFile$.main(ReadCSVFile.scala:15)
    at ReadCSVFile.main(ReadCSVFile.scala)
```

Comment: provide your code as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ jdk-19 is not a supported jdk version:

> Spark runs on Java 8/11/17, Scala 2.12/2.13, Python 3.8+, and R 3.5+. Java 8 prior to version 8u371 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.5.0.

Comment: still the same problem after installing jdk-17 what can I do?

Comment: if possible downgrade to 11 or 8, otherwise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504175/1028537 is the only way to work around the module system